# db2 - Get Week of the Month

Tags: db2

Hello guys I need know the number of the week of a month

For example:

```
Date       | WeekOfTheMonth
2015-04-15 | 3
2015-03-01 | 1
2015-01-08 | 2
```

Beacuse in docs only see **Week of the year**

Thanks

Comment: Assuming your calendar starts on a Sunday, 1) Get the Sunday that's the first day of the month or in the previous month.  2) Calculate the number of days between the Sunday date and your date.  3) Divide the number of days by 7.

Comment: Which do you need - the week starting on the first day of the month (regardless of the actual day-of-week), or always based on a given day (as @Gilbert assumes)?  Side note: if you don't have one, I really recommend a calendar table, wherein you'd store this (and a bunch of other info) permanently for use in queries - getting this information on-the-fly can be expensive.  How are you planning on using this in a query?

Answer (score 0):

Test this SQL query

```
SELECT KURRENT - FIRSTY + 1 FROM ( -- AVOID CURRENT AND FIRST KEYWORD 
   SELECT 
   WEEK_ISO(DATE(1) + (YEAR(date_colum)-1) YEARS + (MONTH(date_colum)-1) MONTHS )AS FIRSTY ,
   WEEK_ISO(date(date_column)) AS KURRENT
FROM TEST_DATE_TABLE
) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT week_iso(current date) - 
       week_iso(last_day(current date) - 1 month + 1 day)
FROM   sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention your platform, but [`VARCHAR_FORMAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-179) has a `W` format string, which gives the week of the month:

> Week of the month (1-5), where week 1 starts on the first day of the
>   month and ends on the seventh day.

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'W') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: @jasilva The error message doesn't help us if you don't show us the code that got the error. If the VARCHAR_FORMAT() function itself isn't rejected, then you have a recent enough version of DB2 (which you haven't told us yet; nor the platform). If argument 1 is rejected, you are using the wrong expression. The VARCHAR_FORMAT() documentation for your DB2 version and platform will tell you what is valid. (We could tell you if we knew what you had.) Try CURRENT TIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT DATE.